# Telling When Couchbase Query Times Out

Tags: c#, .net, memcached, couchbase

I am using couchbase using the .NET client to interact with it. I need to be able to differentiate the cause of a failed call to my couchbase box and log them accurately. I've tried provoking a timeout in my testing environment but I have been unable to.

Reading the .net client [documentation](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-sdk-net-1.1.pdf) it appears that `ExecuteGet` returns an `IGetOperationResult` object that contains both an exception property and a status code property. The status codes would appear to [correspond to this table](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/BinaryProtocolRevamped#Response_Status). I haven't found in the documentation for the .NET client as to whether or not it throws an exception like the Java client. Also, the status codes from the memcached table doesn't seem to have a clear status code value that corresponds to a timeout.

How would one tell whether or not the configured timeout has been exceeded from a call besides not having a value returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The StatusCode property is set only when a response from the server is sent.  A timeout would result in no response from the server, therefore a null StatusCode.  A connection timeout should result in the Exception value being populated on the GetOperationResult...

https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-net-client/blob/2dc8a63208dfa8b991290d128b14002ad4c43f53/src/Enyim.Caching/Memcached/PooledSocket.cs#L68

However, it is quite possible that somewhere further up the Enyim stack, the original timeout exception is being swallowed and rewrapped in another exception.  When you experience timeouts, are you seeing any value for the Exception property?

Comment: I have to add your case only seems to work in CB client 2.0+. If you happen to know about 1.x behavior please add additional information.